# undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, undefined, has-many, belongs-to

upload controller

```
def create
@upload = @order.uploads.build(params[:uploadtwo]) 
   respond_to do |format|
    if @upload.save
    format.html { redirect_to root_path, :notice => 'File was successfully uploaded.' }
    format.json { render :json => @upload, :status => :created, :location => @upload }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.json { render :json => @upload.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }     
end
```

end

upload model

```
belongs_to :order
```

order model

```
has_many :uploads
```

i get error [NoMethodError in UploadtwosController#create ], [undefined method `uploads' for nil:NilClass]

anybody knows what am not doing?

Answer (score 0):

Just declaring `belongs_to :order` in your Upload model does *not* mean that `@order` will automatically be defined in the controller. Perhaps what you want is a `before_filter` in the controller which will set `@order`?

Comment: thanks for very fast response. how will i define it? am new with rails, this is my first app.

Comment: Somewhere in your controller, you'll want to have something like: `before_filter { @order = Order.new(...) }`. What exactly should go in place of `...` depends on what data you want the default `@order` to have. Look up "before_filter" in the Rails Guides for more information.